# Appengine Flex unable to connect on cloudSQL mysql DB

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

I have a Java application running on GAE Flex but it's falling to connect on my private mysql instance with the error:

**at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50) ... 33 common frames omitted Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 2020-08-04 03:16:54 core-api[20200803t145941] The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.**

I've tried the following by Google recommendation:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-shared-vpc#setting_up_permissions

and also a lot of other ways without any luck:

Here are my app.yaml config:

```
service: core-api
runtime: java
env: flex
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk8
env_variables:
  DB_URL: jdbc:mysql://10.115.0.33:3306/database?useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
  DB_USER: user
  DB_PASSWORD: password
network:
  instance_tag: java-app
  name: projects/java-app/global/networks/java-app-network
  subnetwork_name: java-app-subnet1
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: "java-app:southamerica-east1:java-app-mysql-database"
manual_scaling:
  instances: 3
resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 8
  disk_size_gb: 100
```

I'm currently with no clue at all what may be causing suck headache and any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171033/mysql-instance-in-google-cloud-communications-link-failure). Maybe the solution is posted here [7.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_jdbc)

Quote:
"The Google Cloud SQL API must be enabled in your GCP project. To do that, go to the [API library](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library) page of the Google Cloud Console, search for "Cloud SQL API", click the first result and enable the API. "